# firefox animation hardware acceleration pixelated edges

Tags: firefox, animation, css

It seems that css animations on firefox are pixelating the edges of elements:

Here is a reduced case -

```css
.test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 0 14px 14px;
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: move 4s ease 0ms both infinite;
    -moz-animation: move 4s ease 0ms both infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(10deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

This looks fine on webkit, but goes to crap in firefox... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Turns out its a bug in firefox. The bug was filed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this in your element's styling:

```
outline: 1px solid transparent;
```

It's a pretty weird workaround, but should work in your case.

Comment: Yes that worked, wow thanks! Posted a bug with mozilla as well.

Comment: That's really weird! oO

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug? I am be curious to that conversation.